# Subqueries in sqlite. Count the number of selected items in a group

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

When forming a tree of objects, it is necessary to know whether all elements in the group are selected or not.

A group can have subgroups, unlimited nesting. You want to know if all items are selected or multiple items are selected or nothing is selected.

**Is it possible to make one query in SQLite, and find out how many items are selected in a group (including subgroups) and the total number of objects in a group(including subgroups)?**

**I need to find out if all nested elements of a group are selected or not all or nothing is selected**

As a result, you need to get such a state for the group:

```
sealed class GroupSelectState {
    object None: GroupSelectState()//nothing selected
    object Any: GroupSelectState()//at least one item is selected in a folder or in subfolders
    object All: GroupSelectState()//all objects in the folder and subfolders are selected
}
```

**Here is the structure of the tables:**

Group table

```
|  id  | name | parentId |
|  1   | old  | null     |
|  2   | gaz  | 1        |
|  3   | kamaz| 1        |
|  4   | 54901| 3        |
```

Object table

```
|  id  | name       | groupId  |
|  1   | Kamaz 777  | 3        |
|  2   | Kamaz 767  | 3        |
|  3   | Kamaz 677  | 4        |
|  4   | Kamaz 766  | 4        |
|  5   | Gaz 556    | 2        |
```

Table of selected objects (if the object is not in this table, then it is not selected)

```
|  id  | objectId   | isChecked |
|  1   | 1          | 1         |
|  2   | 2          | 1         |
|  3   | 3          | 0         |
|  4   | 4          | 0         |
|  5   | 5          | 0         | // if the object has never been selected, then the table will not have a record for this object
```

Comment: What are you expected results for your sample data? And what's the difference between a group and folder?

Comment: folder = group (I wrote wrong).

Answer (score 0):

For representing hierarchical data in sql database, the Nested Set Approach was invented. Read more on this on wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 0):

First get all child and sub child groups for the selected group

```
;WITH tempTable AS (
    SELECT 
        folderId,
        name,
        parentId
    FROM TreeItemEntity
    WHERE folderId = 20058 (groupId)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t.folderId,
       t.name,
       t.parentId
    FROM
       TreeItemEntity t
       INNER JOIN tempTable c
       ON t.parentId = c.folderId
)

SELECT *
FROM tempTable
```

Result

[image]

Далее получаем объекты для этих групп

```
SELECT * objects where groupId in resultTableIds
```

returned all objects for select group and all child groups. Then we can check the selected objects or not